# SQLite não está criando uma tabela

Tags: sqlite, flutter

Imagens do ERRO que aparece.

SQLite não está criando uma tabela e não consigo resolver o erro, se alguém puder me ajudar

[image: print]

Comment: Detalhe melhor seu problema informando o trecho do código (texto não imagem) onde o erro ocorre. Prefira informar o texto do erro ao invés da imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo código que está sendo exibido na mensagem de erro, você está tentando fazer uma inserção na tabela `table`.

Porém está criando uma tabela com outro nome.

O trecho de código do insert não está na pergunta, vendo pela mensagem de erro exibida o comando correto seria:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (id, nome) VALUES (?,?)
```

Comment: ok, deu certo!!